# Creating calendar view from list programmatically using Elements Module in Sharepoint 2013 apps

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

The following code is displaying my list...the baseview selected is the Calendar view i want but its displaying as a list. How to let SP know this should be displayed as a Calendar?

```
<View List="Lists/HR Transactions" BaseViewID="2" WebPartZoneID="Main" WebPartOrder="1">
            <![CDATA[
                <webParts>
                    <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
                        <metaData>
                            <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
                            <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part</importErrorMessage>
                        </metaData>
                        <data>
                            <properties>
                                <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
                                <property name="Title" type="string">Staff Holiday Calendar</property>
                                <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">False</property>
                            </properties>
                        </data>
                    </webPart>
                </webParts>
                ]]>

        </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Type, Scope, and RecurrenceRowset properties as follows:

```
<View 
    List="Lists/HR Transactions" 
    BaseViewID="2" 
    WebPartZoneID="Main" 
    WebPartOrder="1"
    Type="CALENDAR" 
    Scope="Recursive" 
    RecurrenceRowset="TRUE">
```

Comment: Hey Rich, I have that in the schema.xml as follows <View BaseViewID="2" DisplayName="Holiday Calendar" Type="CALENDAR" WebPartZoneID="Main" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/events.png" Url="calendar.aspx" RecurrenceRowset="TRUE" DefaultView="TRUE" ShowHeaderUI="TRUE"  MobileUrl="_layouts/15/mobile/viewdaily.aspx"> you think i should try putting it in the element.xml?

Comment: I would start with the properties I've listed. Not all of the attributes of the schema's View element are supported for a module's View element. See [View Element (Module)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430995.aspx) for a full list (note that CALENDAR isn't listed as an option for type, but I've seen examples where it works).

Comment: Thanks for that Rich, tried it with no luck...i'm running out of ideas!

Comment: I can tell this definitely works for Modules sections within an onet.xml file for SP 2010. Maybe it doesn't work in a feature separate from a site definition or maybe it is different in SP 2013. But I would think it should work.